# Mobile Menu not working with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So I've got a navigation menu that is working properly in all browsers except Chrome. I'm thinking it may be down to the jquery but I'm not an expert by any means so kinda stumped here.

The HTML code is as follows

```
        <div class="nav-container">
        **<nav class="centered-logo top-bar">**
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img class="logo logo-dark" alt="Logo" src="Images/logotype_dark.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row nav-menu">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 columns text-center">
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <a></a>
                            <li><a href="index.html" target="_self">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="about.html" target="_self">About us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="process.html" target="_self">Process</a></li>
                            <li><a href="topic.html" target="_self">Topic </a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html" target="_self">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mobile-toggle" id="mobile-toggle">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-border"></div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

When the menu icon is clicked the bolded code above should add "open-nav" to it. However it's not working in Chrome.

The jquery is below

```
$('.mobile-toggle').click(function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('open-nav');
});
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us the css so we can see what is the problem..

Comment: The JavaScript seems to be working. It is probably a css problem.

Comment: Post a working code snippet that demonstrates your problem

Comment: So the reply comment I tried to post last night didn't post for some reason. I ended up closing it down (grabbed a drink) and opened back up. Rebuilt the solution tried and it's working now. Not sure what the issue was exactly as it was working in all browsers except Chrome till I did the above.